# Where is the rest of my windows form code

Tags: c#, winforms

Looking at the source code for a windows form application, the class declaration states its a partial class. I understand that this means there are parts of the class in different physical files.

The code in `MyForm.designer.cs` doesnt appear to have a constructor or any means of generating the form. So my question is, where do i find the rest of the code for my windows form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor for `MyForm` is in the main `MyForm.cs` file. Because it is partial, the constructor can reside in `MyForm.cs`, and the generated code can stay in `MyForm.Designer.cs`, allowing for separation of generated and developer-created code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `View Code` option to see the actual source of `MyForm.cs`, which has a constructor as well as all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

MyForm.cs has the constructor and MyForm.designer.cs has the function `private void InitializeComponent()` which will be called from the constructor (in MyForm.cs).

In `private void InitializeComponent()` your components will be created and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Using Partial keyword code can be reside in multiple classes.When you add a window form that creates three files 1. Code file(.CS) 2. Designer file(.Designer.cs) 3. Your Design part. All used Partial keyword.
If you want to see code then double click on design form you will direct to code file there you can find the code and you can handle all the code and events(Developer's Code) like constructor and all.
In Designer.cs you initialize the controls their control properties.It's system generated code but still you can modify.

Hope this helps.....

Comment: The design part _is_ the `.Designer.cs`.  There are only two code files.

Comment: yupp there is designer.cs but when you add a window form then it opens in design mode i am talking about that

Comment: That's not a separate file; it's just VS magic that edits the designer.cs.

Answer (score -1):

Double click on the form will take you there.

Comment: Double-clicking on the form will take the OP to the Load event handler, creating one if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @KeithS: He didn't ask to take you to any specific event... My answer is a quick and easy way to get to the code page he wants. (Don't be an answer Nazi)

Comment: I'm not being an answer Nazi; your answer is wrong. Double-clicking on the form will take you to the non-generated code file, not the generated one which has all the initialization he's interested in. It can also create an unwanted event handler if he wasn't already using a Load handler; while an empty handler technically doesn't hurt anything, it can cause confusion and it's dead weight in your code file.

Comment: @KeithS: You've misunderstood the question. He knows about MyForm.Designer.cs and is looking for MyForm.cs.